# Switching the placement of comma and double-quotes in bibliography (IEEEtran)

Tags: bibliographies

I am using the `IEEEtran.bst` file for formatting the bibliography in a paper I'm writing. Currently the bibliography entries appear in the sequence:

**Author Name, "Article Title,"**

I want to interchange the position of the comma and quotes after *Article Title* such that the bibliography entry appears as

**Author Name, "Article Title",**

Can you please suggest a way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

I just discovered this thread since I was trying to achieve the same.
This is what I did to change the `IEEEtran.bst` formatting.

Move the `quote.close` entry in the `output.nonnull` function up so it ends up at the top. It should look like this:

```
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ swap$
  prev.status.quote quote.close =
     { "''" * }
     { skip$ }
   if$
  prev.status.punct punct.comma =
     { "," * }
     { skip$ }
   if$

  <OMITTED CODE>
}
```

---

In order to retain the comma after the double quotes when the title should end with a punctuation mark, remove the punctuation mark check in the `format.article.title` function. It should look like this:

```
FUNCTION {format.article.title}
{ title duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      "t" change.case$
    }
  if$
  "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { quote.close 'this.status.quote :=
      punct.std 'this.status.punct :=
      select.language
      "``" swap$ *
      cap.status.std
    }
  if$
}
```